# float works as an inline style but not when i move it to an external style sheet

Tags: css, html, css-float, inline

So I'm messing around with asp.net and I seem to be stuck on a CSS problem.  When I float a div right inline it works as expected. However, When I move this style to an external style sheet it doesn't work at all. 
I realize that inline styles have a higher priority and that something might be getting in the way, but I can not seem to figure out what.

Here is my page

```
        <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

***********************the div below that has style="float:right"****************
            <div class="Header"><div style="float:right"><asp:Label ID="lblMasterMessage" runat="server" /></div>Stephen Granets Site!</div>
********************************************************************************

            <div class="ColumnLeft" >
                //stuff
            </div>
                <div class="SiteMap">
                    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">
                        <CurrentNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                        <NodeStyle CssClass="ContentLink" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <RootNodeStyle CssClass="ContentLink" Font-Bold="True" />
                    </asp:SiteMapPath>
                </div>
            <div class="ColumnCenter">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the stylesheet

```
    body {
    }
    .Header
    {
        background-color: #6699FF;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: xx-large;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 40px 0px 0px 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ColumnLeft
    {
        padding: 7px;
        background-color: #6699FF;
        float: left;
    }

    a
    {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:visited
    {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:link
    {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover
    {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .underline
    {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .ColumnCenter
    {
        margin: 7px 7px 7px 175px;
    }
    a:hover.ContentLink
    {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .SiteMap
    {
        font-size: large;
        background-color: #DFEAFF;
    }
```

When I use it in an external stylesheet it is this code

```
 <div class="test">asp label</div>
```

and my css sheet has this added

```
.test
{
   float:right;
}
```

**Question:** So why does the style seem to work when I place it inline, but it does not work when I move that exact piece of code to an external stylesheet?

Comment: If you inspect your element in the Developer tools of your browser, you can often see which rules override which on you element, as overridden rules get a strike-through (at least in Chrome, not sure about the others). So you can track down which styling it is that overrides your setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styles are the last to be applied. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Developer Tools to see if another "closer" style is overriding yours when you make it external (your style will be crossed out).

To supersede even inline styles use [`!important` override](http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/):

```
.test {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Comment: I would strongly discourage using `!important` in production though, better to find the actual problem and sort it out by increasing the specificity of the selector. Using `!important ` your CSS can easily become a mess to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, It's been a while since I've played with CSS and I forgot all about firebug. The problem was that firefox cached  my old stylesheet and my changes weren't being updated. They were, however, being updated when I changed the inline styles. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I agree. The only legitimate use I've seen is to modify sandboxed styles from third-party elements, e.g. social buttons.

Comment: @paislee Agreed, there are a few corner-cases where it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the layout of your code you have some interesting nesting going on here which might be throwing some stuff for a loop.

So you have this:

```
<div class="Header"><div style="float:right"><asp:Label ID="lblMasterMessage" runat="server" /></div>Stephen Granets Site!</div>
```

And you say you switch it to this when you take it to the external stylesheet:

```
<div class="test">asp label</div>
```

So you have a Header div with a div nested inside of it with the  inside of that nested div.  You then close that nested  and add your bit of random text "Stephen Granets Site!" and then you close the Header div.

What if we take this approach:

```
<div class="headerWrapper"><div class="Header">Stephen Granets Site!</div><div class="label"><asp:Label ID="lblMasterMessage" runat="server" /></div></div>
```

This gives you the ability to set something like this for CSS:

```
.headerWrapper{
background-color: #6699FF;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: xx-large;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 40px 0px 0px 10px;
width: 100%;
margin:0 auto; /* this should center align your containing div */
}

.Header{
font-size:large;
float:left;
width:50%;
}

.label{
float:right; /* If you have your paddings and margins set correctly you could just float this to the left as well */

width:50%;
}
```

Does this clear anything up for you?  Are you trying to stack the Header div and the label next to each other? That's what I assumed when I wrote this up.